# Why is this matrix product defined?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

There's this theorem in my book:

> Let $A$ be an $m \times n$ matrix and $B$ be an $n \times p$ matrix. For each $j, j=1,2,\dots,p$, let $u_j$ and $v_j$ denote the $j$th columns of $AB$ and $B$, respectively. Then
>
> - (a) $u_j = Av_j$
> - (b) $v_j = Be_j$, where $e_j$ is the $j$th standard vector of $F^p$.

The dimensions of $B$ and the standard vector $e_j$ are $n \times p$ and $1 \times p$, respectively. I thought matrix multiplication between two matrices with dimensions $a \times b$ and $c \times d$ was only defined when $b=c$! (That's just a normal exclamation mark). But here we have $p$ and $1$ which aren't necessarily equal. What's going on here? The closest explanation I could find was that $e_j$ in this context is a column vector all of a sudden, so its dimensions are now $p \times 1$.

Comment: No,  $e_j$ is of course $p\times 1$. Why are you using row vectors instead of column vectors? “All of a sudden”? Vectors are always column vectors, unless you do computer graphics and multiply by matrices on the right.

Comment: It's a common practice to interpret vectors as matrices of $p\times 1$, that is, as column vectors, precisely to be able to simply multiply $A v$. A few authors prefer the interpretation of a vector as row vectors and write $A v^t$ when they multiply them.

Comment: @TedShifrin up until this point the book was using $e_j$ as a row vector but now that matrices are starting to play a larger role I think that they will be column vectors from now on

Comment: @jjagmath I guess this is it because the author of my book (Friedburg) does exactly this lol

Comment: " up until this point the book was using $e_j$
 as a row vector but now that matrices are starting to play a larger role I think that they will be column vectors from now on" No, it isn't. Since page $8$ Friedberg (not Friedburg) states: "Vectors in $F^n$ may be written as column vectors rather than as row vectors"

Comment: @jjagmath ohhh I see.